# How to add properties to the existing order line item in Shopify?

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

I want to add properties to the existing order line items.

What I have seen so far doesn't help much. According to my experience, it is not possible to add/change properties to existing order line items. Though we can delete line item properties from the admin.

I have found that using grahpql we can add new line item to an existing order, but we can not add line items properties while adding line item this way.